# Print Format SSRS Report For Excel Export

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I created a SSRS Report and I am Exporting it to an Excel Sheet. I am manually print formatting the excel sheet every time I want to print it.
The width of the report that I've created is slightly bigger so every time I print the excel sheet I go to Page Layout --> and set Width to 1 page. 
Is it possible to do this in SSRS itself so that I don't have to make any manual changes to the excel sheet when I export.?

I googled, Couldn't really find any solution.

Layout of my report -
[image]

Other problem I am facing is -
When I export the SSRS report the footer doesn't exported properly
Check This - 
The date doesn't get exported and I want the 'ABC' to appear in the center box but both date and the text appears in the same box.

This is how my footer looks in ssrs -
[image]

Please help. TIA

Comment: You should be able to click the ruler button to show how wide it will be, then from there you can shrink the columns and/or text size to fit on one page. Keep in mind the margins can be set to something smaller too, but you need to account for them in the size.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue with your Footer. It is exported to Excel, but you will not see it on the sheet like you do with the rest of the data. It uses the built in Footer functionality so that it can be repeated on every page.

Go to the Insert menu and click Header & Footer. You should see the footer like this:
[image]

Also, if you go to the Print Preview, you'll see that the footer is indeed repeated on each page.

Regarding the width issue, make sure you take the page margins into account when calculating the width of the report. These can be adjusted in the Report Properties. By default they are set to 1 inch on either side. So right off the bat you may be loosing 2 inches of space.